# Compute $\int_{\gamma} f$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-problem

Let $\gamma_1 = S_1 + L - S_2 - L$ and $\gamma_2 = S_1 + L + S_2 - L$,
$$S_1(t) = e^{it} , t\in [0,2\pi]
$$
$$S_2(t) = 2e^{it} , t\in [0,2\pi]
$$
$$ L = [1,2]
$$
Let $f(z) = (\cos z)/z$. By writing cos z as a power series and considering $f(z) = (1/z)+g(z)$, compute $\int_{\gamma_1} f$ and $\int_{\gamma_2} f$.

Computing the integration seems long so I thought about using the Generalized Version of Cauchy Theorem. Since the winding numbers about the origin add up to 0, the integral is equaled to 0. Am I going about this the right way? (I have not learned the Residue Theorem yet)

Comment: Residue theoem gives the value of the integral as $2\pi i$ since $z=0$ is the only pole and the residue is $1$.

Comment: I have not learned about the Residue Theorem yet, so I cannot apply that here.

Comment: How about Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes i have learned about that

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy's Integral formula says $\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f{(z)}} {z-0} dz=f(0)$. Taking $f(z)=\cos z$ we get the value of the integral immediately as $2\pi i$.